# Kotlin локальный проект

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, плагин

Доброго времени суток. Я хочу создать проект на Kotlin, но не имею доступа к центральным репозиториям напрямую, могу только скачивать нужные библиотеки и класть их в каталог. Подскажите, что нужно скачать и что указать в gradle-конфиге проекта, чтобы у меня начал работать Kotlin в принципе, и Kotlin-jpa в частности.
Использую intellij idea последней версии.

Comment: видимо достаточно скачать сам [плагин Kotlin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin) и вручную установить его.  Как подключить через gradle [написано в офф.документации](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html). Вообще конфиги gradle можно найти в проектах на Gihub аналогичной вашей функциональности.